# Connect mysql database to Ms Access directly

Tags: mysql, vba, microsoft-access, database, microsoft-access-2003

I am trying to connect `mySql` database on our server directly to an `msAccess` database we have. I want to be able to download data from the `mysql database` directly and upload it too directly. I want these things to happen between `tables`.

For example, I have a table in Access called: tableA and in Mysql it is called TableAM. I want to be able to pull data to and from tableA to/from tableAm since they both corresponding tables.

How do I go about this. I am using `MysQl 5.4` and `MsAccess 2003`. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First install the MySQL ODBC driver.  5.1 or 5.2.  I like to set it up for unicode.

Then get the MySQL server running.

Then from Access:  New | Link table | ODBC | MySQL5.1 or MySQL5.2 ODBC Driver and select the base and table you want to link to.

*(There is better documentation elsewhere, and you will probably need to consult it, but this is the nuts and bolts of what you need to do.  If you get stuck, as I'm sure you will I might be able to give you a little help.  But first you must do some more homework based on what I've given you above.  Sorry, I can't give you a better answer right now.  Been awhile since I've done this.  But I do have a working test bed that I could dust off and probably get to work.)*